# ActiveRecord, get only one field (not id) and flatten result array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table and want to get one specific field from every row. When I do `select` I always get id, which I don't want. After that I want to have the result in a simple array.

This is what I do:

```
User.all.select(:reg)
```

This is what I get:

```
[{"id":null,"reg":"erfa"},{"id":null,"reg":"jhzhegrwe"}]
```

This is what I want:

```
{"erfa","jhzhegrwe"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pluck` i believe is what you want, which converts database results in a Ruby array.

This will only return column `:reg`

```
User.all.pluck(:reg)
```